# Lightning Component - Why my data doesn't show in my Utility Bar?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, files, utility-bar

I'm trying to show Files Uploaded in Salesforce File.

I created a Folder in the Libraries part and uploaded the Files inside of it.

So i made a custom aura component to show those files.

**So i made my APEX Controller like this :**

```
public with sharing class FolderItemController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<ContentFolderItem> getContentFolderItem() {
        String folderId = [SELECT Id FROM ContentFolder WHERE Name = :'Modes Opératoires ADV B2B'].Id;
        return [SELECT ContentSize,CreatedById,CreatedDate,FileExtension,FileType,Id,IsDeleted,IsFolder,LastModifiedById,LastModifiedDate,ParentContentFolderId,SystemModstamp,Title 
         FROM ContentFolderItem WHERE ParentContentFolderId = :folderId];
    }
}
```

**And my Aura component like this.**

**ModesOperatoires.cmp :**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="FolderItemController">    
    <!-- Dynamically load the list of contacts -->
    <aura:attribute name="contents" type="List"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="ContentFolderItem" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
    
    <lightning:card variant="Narrow" title="Modes Opératoires B2B/ADV" 
                        iconName="standard:contact">
            <!-- Iterate over the list of contacts and display them -->
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.contents}" var="content">
                <p>
                   File Title : {!v.content.Title}
                </p>
                <p>
                   File Size : {!v.content.ContentSize}
                </p>
                <p>
                   File Extension : {!v.content.FileType}
                </p>
                <p>
                   Owner : {!v.content.CreatedById}
                </p>
            </aura:iteration>            
        
        </lightning:card> 
</aura:component>
```

**ModesOpertatoires.js :**

```
({
    init: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.getModesOperatoires(component);
    }
})
```

**ModesOperatoiresHelper.js :**

```
({
    getModesOperatoires : function(component) {
        var action = component.get("c.getContentFolderItem");
        
        //Set up the callback
        var self = this;
        action.setCallback(this, function(actionResult) {
            var state = actionResult.getState();
            console.log(state);
            console.log(actionResult.getReturnValue());
            console.log(component.isValid());
            if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.contents", actionResult.getReturnValue());
            }            
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

**But at the end, i can see the Data in my Browser Console but not in the Utility Bar Shortcut where i'm using the component.**

[image]

If you guys can enlighten where my mistake is would help me a lot.

Comment: What is the purpose of `recordId` attribute in your component?

Comment: To get the ID of my 2 Files in the Folder, but i'm wondering if it's not the reason of my issue.

Comment: Can you try and see if setting of `v.contents` property inside the if statement is being executed.

Comment: Like this ? `if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS" && "v.contents") {
                console.log("v.contents");
                component.set("v.contents", actionResult.getReturnValue());
                console.log(actionResult.getReturnValue());
            }          `

Comment: yes, like that.

Comment: Well yes i still had my logs with the data in my browser console, but still not showing in my component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have **typo here**. You can see your iteration happened already 2 times. Only data is not displaying.

In aura iteration we don't use **V** tag. Ref - [Example in Aura Doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:iteration/example)

Please try with this -

```html
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="FolderItemController">    
    <!-- Dynamically load the list of contacts -->
    <aura:attribute name="contents" type="List"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="ContentFolderItem" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
    
    <lightning:card variant="Narrow" title="Modes Opératoires B2B/ADV" 
                        iconName="standard:contact">
            <!-- Iterate over the list of contacts and display them -->
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.contents}" var="content">
                <p>
                   File Title : {! content.Title}
                </p>
                <p>
                   File Size : {! content.ContentSize}
                </p>
                <p>
                   File Extension : {! content.FileType}
                </p>
                <p>
                   Owner : {! content.CreatedById}
                </p>
            </aura:iteration>            
        
        </lightning:card> 
</aura:component>
```

Comment: good catch! `v.` in aura component is the new hide and seek champion after `;`.

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you very much.

Comment: @Raul - yeah really :D